# Garry's mod lua, attempt to call method error

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am testing out Garry's Mod Lua And a strange error keeps poping up!

This error seems to be popping up whenever i use any Glua classes, Such as Player:kill!

this is my error

```
[ERROR] lua/test.lua:6: attempt to call method 'Kill' (a nil value)
```

And here is the code i am using

```
function killplayer()


 local ply = LocalPlayer()

 ply:Kill()

end

killplayer()
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function killplayer()
  if !(LocalPlayer() and LocalPlayer():Alive()) then return end
  LocalPlayer():Kill()
end
```

Comment: [ERROR] lua/test.lua:6: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got userdata)
  1. pairs - [C]:-1
   2. killplayer - lua/test.lua:6
    3. unknown - lua/test.lua:12

Comment: then forget about for-loop, and try to just `print(ply)`. It will show if `ply` exists on the time when you call it.

Comment: Just, [Documentation](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Global/LocalPlayer) says it will be nil until all the things will be initialized...

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `lua_openscript test.lua`? Because you have to run this script on server side, because `Kill()` is function working only on server side.